# How to get value of updated state immediatly in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

In the following I am updating the value of a state and then trying to use it inside useEffect only but cannot get the value of the updated state can anyone help me regarding how can i get updated state immediately inside useEffect only

Thank you

```
    useEffect(() => {
                dispatch(setSecondaryInvName(barcodeData))
                console.log("secondaryInventoryName == ", secondaryInventoryName)
            }
    })
```

Comment: you can add the state value as a dependency: useEffect(() => {
  //your logic
}, [*your state property*]); You'll need some logic to avoid infinite loops.

Comment: `barcodeData` is the new value, right? Why can't you just use it?

Answer (score 2):

you shouldn't and you cant.

first use useEffect like componentDidMount with []:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(setSecondaryInvName(barcodeData))
}, [])
```

then you should use useEffect like componentDidUpdate with [secondaryInventoryName]:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("secondaryInventoryName == ", secondaryInventoryName)
}, [secondaryInventoryName])
```

Comment: thank you for a quick response but after setting the value of secondaryinventory i have to call an api instantly whenever i scan the barcode but if I do as you have suggested and call api in the second useEffect then api will be called everytime whenever I update the value of secondaryInventory but I want to call api if the secondaryInventory's value is updated but scanner

Comment: I didnt get what you want, you want to call your api "if secondaryInventory's value is updated" but not "whenever you update the value of secondaryInventory" ? arent those the same things?

Comment: there are two scenarios when my secondaryInventory will be update first when I type something in textfield of secondaryInventory and second is when I will scan the barcode of inventory so whenever i scan the barcode my api should be called not when I type something inside textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get immediately updated value in useEffect instead of you have to make a dependency in useEffect whenever its value will update it will trigger.
Like:

```
useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(setSecondaryInvName(barcodeData))
         
        }
},[])
 useEffect(() => {
            
            console.log("secondaryInventoryName == ", secondaryInventoryName)
        }
},[secondaryInventoryName])
```